# Mysql Queries cause high load in server

Tags: mysql, innodb, linux

I have problem in the database ,here is phpmyadmin status queries

```
--------------------+                                                                                                                    53:22
| Id   | User         | Host      | db           | Command | Time | State        | Info
+------+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------+
| Id   | User         | Host      | db           | Command | Time | State        | Info
                    |
+------+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------+
| 2667 | leechprotect | localhost | leechprotect | Sleep   | 508  |              |
                    |
| 4354 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
| 4357 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
| 4358 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
| 4359 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
| 4362 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
| 4363 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
| 4364 | Data_User   | localhost | Data_Name   | Query   | 86   | Sending data | SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW
()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR |
```

here is sql queires

```
SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
# User@Host: Data_User[Data_User] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 94.999872  Lock_time: 0.000046 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 466611
SET timestamp=1401044204;
SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
# User@Host: Data_User[Data_User] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 94.120904  Lock_time: 0.000030 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 466613
SET timestamp=1401044204;
SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
# Time: 140525 20:56:45
# User@Host: Data_User[Data_User] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 95.266550  Lock_time: 0.000032 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 466612
SET timestamp=1401044205;
SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
# User@Host: Data_User[Data_User] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 95.262194  Lock_time: 0.000029 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 466612
SET timestamp=1401044205;
SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
# User@Host: Data_User[Data_User] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 94.973241  Lock_time: 0.000031 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 466612
SET timestamp=1401044205;
SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id='0' AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```

How could I fix the IP2Files table ?

update :

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE IP2Files;
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| IP2Files | CREATE TABLE `IP2Files` (
  `file_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usr_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owner_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `money` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `referer` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`,`ip`,`usr_id`),
  KEY `owner` (`owner_id`),
  KEY `user` (`usr_id`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`,`created`),
  KEY `date` (`created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)




mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(money) FROM IP2Files;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | IP2Files | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 446977 |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>




mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id=0 AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   114001 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.59 sec)
```

Comment: The table needs no "fixing". An index on `(usr_id, created, money)` will probably fix the issue - which seems to be the queries doing a full table scan (466K rows examined,)

Comment: Do you have indexes on the table? Have you checked the EXPLAIN plan?

Comment: @ypercube would you please give me the mysql command for the information you need ? so i can edit my question with it

Comment: The outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE IP2Files;` and `EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(money) FROM ...`

Comment: i update my question with the output of the two commands

Comment: Can you tell us what the result of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IP2Files WHERE usr_id=0 AND created>NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR;`

Comment: @ypercube i update my question with this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected (from the 90+ seconds they were spending), the queries are doing a full table scan, reading all 460K rows.

Add an index on `(usr_id, created, money)` and it will be substantially faster:

```
ALTER TABLE databasename.IP2Files
  ADD INDEX usr_id_created_money_IX      -- pick a name for the index
    ON (usr_id, created, money) ;
```

---

Unrelated to the issue, since `usr_id` is of integer datatype, you shouldn't compare it with string literals. Instead of `WHERE usr_id='0'`, use `WHERE usr_id=0`

Comment: -- pick a name for the index this should be any name ? and where exactly should i execute this query , inside the table IP2Files or inside the database Data_Name ?

Comment: Missed the table name, edited the answer. Execute it either from the command line, or PHPMyadmin.

Comment: there is something weird , i was going to execute this query but i take a look first to the mysqladmin status i see there is no this sending data queries ??? i didn't execute the command yet ! should i execute the query ? or i wait till this problem happen again

Comment: I don't know about the details of phpmyadmin. The index should be added **once** (it should take some time to be created but not very long, it's not a huge table.). You can check if it is added by running the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..` again (or with phpmyadmin by going to table structure->indexes or something like that.)